# Real Analysis: function achieves minimum value

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**
Suppose that $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and that no point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in both $A$ and $B$, and neither $A$ nor $B$ are empty. For each point $a\in A$, let $f(a)$ be the infimum of the distances $|b-a|$ to all points $b\in B$. Prove that there is a closest point of $A$ to $B$, or in other words that $f$ achieves a minimum value at some point $a_0\in A$.

**Attempt**
This is a proof I'm having real trouble with, any help towards a final answer would be greatly appreciated. I think its an extreme value theorem proof but I can't quite wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance.

I know that a compact set is closed, which A is. If I can show A⊂B then A will be compact but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Hint: You can reduce it to the case that $A$ is compact too.

Comment: Hey Daniel thanks for the reply. I know that a compact set is closed, which $A$ is. If I can show $A\subset B$ then $A$ will be compact but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: No, you have $A \cap B = \varnothing$, so you can't have $A \subset B$, since $A$ is nonempty. Try to find a compact $C\subset A$ such that $$\inf \{ f(a) : a \in A\} = \min \{ f(c) : c \in C\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A very rough sketch of a proof**:

So $f$ is a function $A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  First, you want to show that $f$ is continuous.  This will come in handy later.

Define a subset $Y \subset A$ where $\displaystyle x \in Y \iff \inf_{b \in B}d(x, b) > c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $f(Y) > f(A \setminus Y)$, it follows that the minimum value, if it exists, will exist somewhere in $A \setminus Y$.  Well, $A \setminus Y$ is compact, and so what do we know about the continuous image of a compact set?  It is compact!  What can we conclude?

Comment: If $inf\in A$ then $infA=minA$. Is this the final line? Thanks for the reply Kaj

Comment: Kind of.  I think you mean to have some $f(A)$'s in there.  I guess the point is just that, since $f(A \setminus Y)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, we know it must be a closed and bounded set which has a minimum/infimum.  So $f$ achieves a minimum on the domain $A \setminus Y$, and since $f(Y) > f(A \setminus Y)$ due to how we defined $Y$, we know $f$ achieves a minimum on all of $A$.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks for the help.